# What is wrong with my code? Cannot extend list in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get input from a line, which consists of a string and n integers separated by spaces.

Example input:

```
"abcd" 1 3 4 5
```

Expected output:

```
abcd
1
3
4
5
```

My approach is to consider first string as a list and extend it with list of integers constructed using map

```
li = input().split()
lin = [li[0]].extend( list(map(int,li[1:])) )
for i in len(lin) :
    print (lin[i])
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just won't do:

```
lin = [li[0]].extend( list(map(int,li[1:])) )
```

As `.extend` returns `None`.

Instead use

```
lin = [li[0]]
lin.extend( list(map(int,li[1:])) )
```

And as `.extend` takes an iterable, the extra list call can be removed:

```
lin = [li[0]]
lin.extend(map(int,li[1:]))
```

Or:

```
lin = [li[0]] + list(map(int,li[1:])) )
```